# scipy.integrate.quad ctypes function error "quadpack.error: quad: first argument is a ctypes function pointer with incorrect signature"

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, ctypes, numerical-integration

I am trying to use `scipy.integrate.nquad` with a `ctypes` function. I exactly followed the instruction on [Faster integration using Ctypes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#faster-integration-using-ctypes).

> `ctypes` integration can be done in a few simple steps:
>
> 1. Write an integrand function in C with the function signature `double f(int n, double args[n])`, where `args` is an array containing the arguments of the function `f`.
>
> ```
> //testlib.c
>
> double f(int n, double args[n])    
> {
>    return args[0] - args[1] * args[2]; //corresponds to x0 - x1 * x2
> }
> ```
>
> 2. Now compile this file to a shared/dynamic library (a quick search will help with this as it is OS-dependent). The user must link any math libraries, etc. used. On Linux this looks like:
>
> ```
> $ gcc -shared -o testlib.so -fPIC testlib.c
> ```
>
> The output library will be referred to as `testlib.so`, but it may have a different file extension. A library has now been created that can be loaded into Python with `ctypes`.
>
> 3. Load shared library into Python using `ctypes` and set `restypes` and `argtypes` - this allows Scipy to interpret the function
>      correctly:
>
> ```
> >>> import ctypes
>
> >>> from scipy import integrate
>
> >>> lib = ctypes.CDLL('/**/testlib.so') # Use absolute path to testlib
>
> >>> func = lib.f # Assign specific function to name func (for simplicity)
>
> >>> func.restype = ctypes.c_double
>
> >>> func.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_double)
> ```
>
> Note that the argtypes will always be `(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_double)` regardless of the number of parameters, and restype will always be `ctypes.c_double`.
>
> 4. Now integrate the library function as normally, here using `nquad`:
>
> ```
> >>> integrate.nquad(func, [[0,10],[-10,0],[-1,1]])
>
> (1000.0, 1.1102230246251565e-11)
> ```

However, at the final step, I didn't get the result of the integral, but the following errors instead:

```
>>> integrate.nquad(func,[[0,1.0],[-2.0,3.0],[1.0,2.0]])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/bfn097/apps/scipy/0.13.3_mkl-11.1.2_gcc-4.4.7/lib64/python/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 618, in nquad
      return _NQuad(func, ranges, opts).integrate(*args)

  File "/home/bfn097/apps/scipy/0.13.3_mkl-11.1.2_gcc-4.4.7/lib64/python/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 670, in integrate

    value, abserr = quad(f, low, high, args=args, **opt)

  File "/home/bfn097/apps/scipy/0.13.3_mkl-11.1.2_gcc-4.4.7/lib64/python/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 254, in quad

    retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)

  File "/home/bfn097/apps/scipy/0.13.3_mkl-11.1.2_gcc-4.4.7/lib64/python/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 319, in _quad

    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

  File "/home/bfn097/apps/scipy/0.13.3_mkl-11.1.2_gcc-4.4.7/lib64/python/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 670, in integrate

    value, abserr = quad(f, low, high, args=args, **opt)

  File "/home/bfn097/apps/scipy/0.13.3_mkl-11.1.2_gcc-4.4.7/lib64/python/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 254, in quad

    retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)

  File "/home/bfn097/apps/scipy/0.13.3_mkl-11.1.2_gcc-4.4.7/lib64/python/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 319, in _quad

    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

  File "/home/bfn097/apps/scipy/0.13.3_mkl-11.1.2_gcc-4.4.7/lib64/python/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 670, in integrate

    value, abserr = quad(f, low, high, args=args, **opt)

  File "/home/bfn097/apps/scipy/0.13.3_mkl-11.1.2_gcc-4.4.7/lib64/python/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 254, in quad

    retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)

  File "/home/bfn097/apps/scipy/0.13.3_mkl-11.1.2_gcc-4.4.7/lib64/python/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 319, in _quad

    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

quadpack.error: quad: first argument is a ctypes function pointer with incorrect signature
```

I am using gcc-4.4.7,python 2.6.6, numpy-1.7.1, scipy-0.13.3

Comment: `double args[n]` in function signatures is identical to `double *args`

Comment: You have followed [faster-integration-using-ctypes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.0/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#faster-integration-using-ctypes). It seems it is a new feature that doesn't exist in [0.14](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) or [0.13](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/tutorial/integrate.html).

Comment: I am using scipy-0.15.1. `integrate.nquad(func,[[0,1.0],[-2.0,3.0],[1.0,2.0]])` yields `(-1.25, 1.4017986003800292e-13)` where `func` is the `ctypes` function in your question.

Comment: @nymk you are right. I tried 0.15.1, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the argument should be: `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)`

But have you considered using `cffi`? Besides being faster than `ctypes`, you also don't have to hand-write the argument stuff, just copy the C declarations and let `cffi` parse them.

Comment: `scipy.integrate.quad` doesn't understand `cffi`, only `ctypes` functions.